# CALayer properties (ex: drop shadows) not appearing on all UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-animation, calayer

So I have a `UIView` in a prototype `UITableViewCell`. In that view's `awakeFromNib` method, I have the following code to make a shadow

```
CALayer *layer = self.layer;

layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

// Makes shadow for each cell in all and nearby table views.

CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
CGFloat curlFactor = 15.0f;
CGFloat shadowDepth = 5.0f;

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width, 0.0f)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size.width, size.height + shadowDepth)];
[path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, size.height + shadowDepth)
        controlPoint1:CGPointMake(size.width - curlFactor, size.height + shadowDepth - curlFactor)
        controlPoint2:CGPointMake(curlFactor, size.height + shadowDepth - curlFactor)];

self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 7.0f);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.layer.shadowPath =  path.CGPath; //Sets a path for the shadow. Greatly enhances performance.
```

The problem is that the shadow only appears on some cells, not all and seems to be random at times. I tried putting the code in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` but it didn't work all together in there either. Does anyone have a clue of what can possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally realized that the problem is that the drop shadows are not missing, they were just overlapped by other cells.

So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10166301/90172) can solve the problem (you'll need `sendSubviewToBack:` in this case).

FYI, the new [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) in iOS 6 will give you more control over cell z-indices, and for pre-iOS 6 support, [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) is a nice alternative.