# iOS: UITableView scrollbar hidden by subview

Tags: ios, scrollbar, tableview

My UITableView has a subview with a fixed position. But when I scroll, the scrollbar is hidden by the subview. How can I avoid this?

## EDIT ##

```
self.menuViewRelative = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.menuViewRelative.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.menuViewRelative.opaque = YES;
self.menuViewRelative.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -1.0, 320.0, 50.0);
[self.view insertSubview:self.menuViewRelative atIndex:11];
```

This subview is now above 10 other subviews and exactly 1 layer under the scrollView (so it displays the scroll indicator perfectly).

Comment: Set `scrollIndicatorInsets` for the table view in such a way that the scroller will be moved in a place where subview wont overlap.

For eg:-

`self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 7.0);`

Comment: @ACB You should make that an answer!

Comment: @JesseRusak,Thanks. I have added as an answer. I was waiting for someone to give a better answer and I didn't want OP to miss this one as well. Hence added as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `addSubview:` for this? That will make it the top-most subview, which will cover the scroll bars. If you instead use `insertSubview:atIndex:` and ensure it's *just* above the other content in your table view, it will be below the scroll bars.

You might need to override `layoutSubviews` of the UITableView (like I describe in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166147/overlapping-uitableviewcell-content-views/10166301#10166301)) and look through the contents of the table view in order to keep your floating view just above the table view cells.

Comment: wow :) I just got one problem: the first separator line scrolls over the subview. I solved this by adding `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.menuViewRelative];`. But when I call that snippet, the scrollbar is hidden.

Comment: Yeah, you can't call `bringSubviewToFront:` because then it will cover the scroll indicators; you need to use `insertSubview:atIndex:` to move it just below the scroll indicators in your layoutSubviews implementation.

Comment: and how can I achieve the result of both functions? Like I said: the first separator is over the subview.

Comment: please have a look at the first post

Comment: Are you overriding layoutSubviews of the table view as I suggested? You need to override that and move your subview to the right place in the list of subviews in there.

Comment: You need to override layoutSubviews of the *UITableView*.

Comment: excuse me jesse, but I don't know how to achieve that.. can you post some code?

Comment: You need to create a subclass of UITableView, and set the class for the UITableView in your nib to be that subclass. Try Googling around for subclassing and how to override the class of a UITableView.

Answer (score 4):

Adding as an answer as per Jesse Rusak's comment.

Set `scrollIndicatorInsets` for the table view in such a way that the scroller will be moved in a place where subview wont overlap.

For eg:-

```
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 7.0);
```

Comment: great answer. the problem is: the subview covers horizontally the full screen (320 pixel). should be a 'floating menu'.